# How to continue the execution of parent function after redirecting to and from the child / grand child page - React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I am a newbie to React Native and also not so strong in JS, so kindly bare with me and help me out in this scenario.

I have a page A. When on clicking a switch it triggers some function(s), Lets say like

Parent Page A - ***enableInsurance***

```
function switch(insuredID){
   if (noCreditCard){
     navigator.navigate('paymentPage',{navigateKey:"ObjectsDetailPage"}); //Takes user to payment page to choose payment mode
   }
   
   /* On re-navigation after adding CreditCard I need to continue doing below lines */
   object.isInsured = true;
   const { updateAction } = this.props;
   updateAction();
   this.setState({ showFlatrateText: false });
}
```

In our scenario there is no credit card so the user is navigated to ***paymentPage*** where he can select mode of payment like Card, paytm, etc.

```
goToPaymentWebview = (Type) => {
  NetInfo.fetch()
    .then(resp => { 
       if(resp.isConnected){
            this.setState({showNetDownModal:false});
            NavigationService.navigate('paymentWebview',{navigateTo: this.props.navigation.getParam('navigateKey'));
        } else {
            this.setState({showNetDownModal:true});
        }
     });        
  }
```

After selecting the mode the user is taken to grand Child page - ***paymentWebview*** and load in webview.

Once the user fills the details and submits, then I navigate the user back to the *Parent Page A* on the success or failure callback of the detail submission in webview as below

Grand Child Page - ***paymentWebview***

```
if(respJSON.status === 'success') {
   const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
   setTimeout(() => {
      switch(this.state.navigateTo){
         case "ObjectsDetailPage":
             navigate('enableInsurance');
         break;
         case "ObjectPage":
             navigate('ObjectPageScreen');
         break;
         default:
             navigate('Second',{ccUpdate: respJSON});
       }
    }, 2000);
 }
```

Now I am back to the page from where I got redirected to payment page using *navigateKey* param,
In our case its Parent Page A - *enableInsurance*

But after navigating back here how can i execute the same *function switch(insuredID){ ... }*  and proceed with the functionality

- React-Native 0.63.4,
- React-navigation 4.x,

Creating app for both iOS and Android, navigation is using Stacknavigator , there is no tab navigation.

Comment: hi jalil, how is this switch(insuredID) method getting executed the very first time ?

Comment: Also how this noCreditCard variable is set in the component.

Comment: Hi @boredbear153 this switch function is just one among many function
this switch function is called by onClick like * <TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this.switch(item)} /> *
But this creditcard check is done in multiple places with in the application
In some places it will be called by another function which doesnot have any parameters. Some times it will be called from a different function with multiple parameters.

Comment: Hey, ideally when we enter CC info this noCreditCard flag will be turned to false. And upon returning back to parent page, i am assuming by default the switch method will be triggered. In this case, as noCreditCard is false, the code inside if will not be executed..

Comment: Find the method that executes on load of the Parent page & handle logic as required.

Comment: alternatively, you can also try passing a new param whenever credit card info is updated. 
  case "ObjectsDetailPage":
             navigate('enableInsurance', {ccUpdated:true});
When enableInsurance page loads, you can always check for the presence of "ccUpdated" param. if it is present, then perform next steps.

Comment: @boredbear153 my issue is in reactnative and when we redirect to the page using navigate or goback it will execute componentDidmount or componentWillmount only 
so from that how can we trigger this switch(insuredID). and how the insuredID will be retained while we returned to the page.
Secondly in the same page there are two more functions with or without multiple parameters insuranceturnOn(), createEvent(bagId, userId, cartValue) , even these functions have this credit card check , so how can I determine which function to invoke on page load if we are returning back

Comment: Hey,when we redirect to the page using navigate or goback it will execute componentDidmount or componentWillmount  =>

you can create a new method in this componentDidMount lifecycle & add your logic. in  your state, you should have the credit card information available. So try to validate that in a new method & take appropriate action. We dont have to use the switch method for this..

if you want to track the insuredId, add a new state as currentInsuredID and track of it.

Comment: It would be a double load,
then in each page i should write or call all the corresponding functions and also create a new state to store all the parameter values , do we have to make it so difficult. Isnt there anything like a promise or service so we dont divert from the parent function